# Firebase dynamic links invalid

Tags: ios, firebase-dynamic-links

I have used my bundle identifier as the url scheme, lets say that it is "foo.bar".

I am debugging my app in the emulator and safari by typing in "foo.bar://" and it opens my app.

However, the link that firebase is using looks something like:
"foo.bar://google/link?deep_link_id=12312312"
When I enter that into safari it says "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid."

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: Having the same problem.